# Vertically align text and button inside Bootstrap 3 alert

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically align text (pulled left) and a button (pulled right) inside a Bootstrap 3 `alert`. Somehow like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| Some text                           [A button] |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

What I have so far is the following ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117252)):

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style="overflow:hidden">
    <p class="pull-left">Some text</p>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">A button</button>
</div>
```

The button is perfectly aligned (this was actually my first problem, solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169717/align-button-vertically-in-alert-field)), but now the text is out of center.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you set up a fiddle for this?

Comment: @Travis I already included a link to a bootply, why do you need a fiddle?

Comment: HAHA i missed that sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use line-height, you can also try:

```
div.alert-info {
    position: relative;
}

div.alert-info p.pull-left {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/117260

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seems like the most flexible to me.

Answer (score 2):

use `display:table; width:100%;` for the alert div, and for the `p` tag remove the float and use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle`. 
You can use the same rules for the button.

Answer (score -2):

Here ya go i updated bootply here http://www.bootply.com/117259

All i did was add some line height on the pull-left class

```
 .pull-left{line-height:30px}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: And if different alerts have different amounts of text? The line height would have to be adjusted. What about if he needs to use `.pull-left` somewhere else?

Comment: Agreed but that wasn't the question, just use an ID for this particular alert... upated bootply http://www.bootply.com/117264