# A inconvenient white space on ul

Tags: html, css, css-float

i'm trying to put a ul next to the image but every time somehow still a white space above the ul, so i would like to know if this is normal.

thanks[image]

```
.card {float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.card ul {float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding:0;
margin:0;
width:auto;

}
.card img {float: left;
  }



<div class="block3">

     <div class="clearfix"> 
 <% @users.each do |user| %>  
     <div class="card">
  <%= link_to(image_tag(user.avatar.url(:post).to_s),user_url(user.id)) %>
  <ul>
    <li class="clearfix">

  <li>
     <p class="name">

            <%= link_to user_path(user.id) do %>
        <%= user.name %> <%= user.surname %>
      <% end %>          
    </p>
  </li>            
</li>
</ul>  
</div> 
<% end %> 
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including HTML, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: can you please put up a fiddle!?

Comment: Since this is a CSS-related question, not Ruby on Rails, please include the generated HTML markup (view source and copy in your browser) rather than the raw Ruby template code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the element with Firebug or in Chrome (right-click -> Inspect Element) and check if there is any default styling, either from your browser or any default stylesheet you're using. This will also tell you the source of the styling.

It looks like you're adding the name as a `<p>` element -- Firefox and Safari both add 1em margin to paragraphs by default (https://stackoverflow.com/a/819190/1255142) so that may be your problem right there.

You may also want to use a CSS reset template clear out the defaults.

Comment: +1 most cross-browser inconsistencies can be addressed with a CSS reset such as Normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with your list items in `ul`. Since I can't see your code, check your line height, margin, and padding on those list items. For example, if you have a top and bottom margin on your list items, just use bottom margin to separate them.

Comment: so the line height, can create this spaces too?