# What is the default margin value of <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I noticed that the `<p>` tag has a default margin value and it seems it's somehow related to its content's `font-size` value.

Is there any reference that I can check out the detailed rules for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/z45R9/ Please take a look at my code here.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Different Browsers are built upon different *render engines*.

Chrome and Safari use the WebKit-render engine, whereas Firefox uses Gecko.

The **different engines** are different not just because the **software** is different but also because they have different **settings**. That's why most web pages look slightly different in different browsers.

---

**The Answer:**

In Chrome (webkit), the margin-top *(above the element)* and margin-bottom *(below the element)* of the `<p>` tag is 1em.

In Firefox (Gecko), all margins are 0 except the margin-bottom, which is 1em again.

The way to get rid of this problem is to make a [CSS-reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).
The easiest to use would be the one by [Meyerweb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Thanks, but I found it's the same from Firefox & Chrome. What do you mean by "in mozilla the margin is 0"?

Comment: in mozilla the top-margin is 0, the left-margin is 0, the right-margin is 0 and the bottom-margin is 1em

Comment: in chrome the top-margin should be 1em, this shouldnt be your problem if you reset and redefine your css

the reset can be done with `*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}` in your css

Comment: the distance between the element and the element above

Comment: so that is `margin-top` ?

Comment: yes, i wasnt using the correct css-terminology

Answer (score 2):

The default value of

margin depends on the browser. For example, the CSS 2.1 especification define [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) default stylesheet for HTML 4. But some browsers can use this, and others not. Its not a rule, just a reference.

Comment: Just say it. In the answer. The link can become broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different browsers, and they all can have their own unique way to do things. For that reason, most designers put a css reset in their css stylesheet.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

By putting that reset in your file, it will enable you to better control how your website looks on all browsers. Instead of worrying about what each browsers default is for each thing.

Comment: Try answering the question.

Comment: I think this is also quite helpful! Thanks! I need my website to work exactly the same in every browser!