# jQuery get height of the contents in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm not even sure if this is possible but I want to get the height of the contents in a container. Let's assume I have

```
<div id="container" style="min-height:100vh">
    <div class="child">
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="another-child">
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the true height of the content of `#container`? Those inline heights are just as example to show parent height could be anything. I want to know how much the content are truly occupying. Again assuming that there could be an arbitrary number of child tags.

**note** in the example above the true height is the height of those paragraphs combined if they aren't inline.

Comment: Did you even search the web for a solution?

Comment: So you don't mean you want to know its 100% height. or say your browser window is 800px high, it tells you 800px but rather how many pixels the two lines below each other use, even though you have set a different height on the container?

Comment: Of course I searched the web. I've been searching for 2 days! You don't need to vote down if you didn't understand the question

Comment: No I do not care about converting % to px! I want to know the height of content inside the bigger parent (not the height of the parent but the height of content combined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this can be done using single `jQuery/javascript` function . But this snippet can be useful

HTML

```
 // Added a common class to all child element of div#container
     <div id="container" style="min-height:100vh">
        <div class="child cc">
          <p>Some </br>text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="another-child cc">
          <p>Some text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
// Loop through all child element using common class to get the total height
var cc = 0;
    $("#container > div.cc").each(function(){
        cc += $(this).outerHeight();
    });
$('#height').append('<p>'+ cc+'</p>' );
```

CSS

```
 p{
    margin:0px;
        }
```

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850594/what-is-the-default-margin-value-of-p-tag)  if you want to know why setting `margin:0`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/3a626508/)

**EDIT**

Add an iterator to exclude `inline` elements. Also the `.each` is iterating on elements which has `cc` class. So you can made `inline` not to have `cc` class.

Here is a snippet of checking `display` type of the element before adding their height.

```
var cc = 0;
    $("#container > .cc").each(function(){
      var getDisplay = $(this).attr('dipslay') // Check the display attribute
       // Using ternary operator 
       getDisplay !=='inline'? (cc += $(this).outerHeight()) :0;
     });
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/3a626508/2/)

Comment: But what if the children are inline? That will only work for block displayed item correct?

Comment: Still a flawed answer. Broken for inline-block, for inline children that wrap, for children that float, etc. I suppose the real solution is to subtract min and max y coordinates over all children edges with [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). But I wonder if that has to contend with [positioning coordinate variations](http://javascript.info/coordinates).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)-functions of jQuery:

```
$('#container').height();
```

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements

Or

```
$('#container').innerHeight();
```

> Get the current computed inner height (including padding but not border) for the first element in the set of matched elements

Or

```
$('#container').outerHeight();
```

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin

---

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/un0j15oy/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try using `window.getComputedStyle(/* DOM element */).getPropertyValue("height")`

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle($("#container")[0]).getPropertyValue("height"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="container" style="min-height:100vh">
  <div class="child" style="height:100%">
    <div class="another-child">
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="another-child">
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just a small doubt why do it is consoling 200px but on you hover on the DOM using chroome dev's tool you may see height of div.child is 68px and div#container height is equal to height of screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery method
`$("selector").height();`
This will return you how much your container is occupying.

Comment: the CONTENTS in a container

Answer (score 0):

```
                  var cc = 0;
                  $("#"+currenId2c+ "> .cc").each(function(){
                  var getDisplay = $(this).attr('dipslay')
                      getDisplay !=='inline'? (cc += $(this).outerHeight()) :0;
                  });
                  var cnt = cc;
                  console.log(cnt);
```