# Unwanted spacing between html elements

Tags: html, css

It appears as if there is padding between two of my elements - content1 and footer. I do not want this 'padding' but I cannot understand why it is there at all. Here is part of problematic html text on its own - the 'padding' still appears. I've tried adding in padding: 0 and margin: 0 to both the elements with no result.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 512px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: gray;
    z-index: 5;
}
.content1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    z-index: 5;
}
.imagecontainer{
    height: 80%;
    float: right;
}
.image{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="content1">
        <!--<div class="textcontainer">
            <p style="color: gray; font-size: 15px; font-family: arial;">this is some text</p>
    </div>-->
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img class="image" src="C:\Users\wrigh\Pictures\SWITCH\capture01.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <center><p style="padding-top:50px; max-width: 50%;">ONLY AVAILIBLE ON ANDROID<br><br>UPDATE: NO CURRENT WORK IS SCHEDULED</p></center>
    </div>
</body>
```

In response to the proposed answer to this question. I have removed the image from the text and unfortunately the 'padding' was not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

When elements have top or bottom margin, and the parent element doesn't have a border or padding, the margins collapes. The effect is that the margin is visible outside the parent element, not between the parent element boundaries and the child element.

It's the margin of the `p` element in the footer that is collapsing. It creates the distance between the `content1` and the `footer` element.

By removing the margin on the `p` element, you get rid of the distance:

```
.footer p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}
.footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 512px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: gray;
    z-index: 5;
}
.content1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    z-index: 5;
}
.imagecontainer{
    height: 80%;
    float: right;
}
.image{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content1">
        <!--<div class="textcontainer">
            <p style="color: gray; font-size: 15px; font-family: arial;">this is some text</p>
    </div>-->
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img class="image" src="C:\Users\wrigh\Pictures\SWITCH\capture01.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <center><p style="padding-top:50px; max-width: 50%;">ONLY AVAILIBLE ON ANDROID<br><br>UPDATE: NO CURRENT WORK IS SCHEDULED</p></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: If this is a "margin collapse" problem, you should have voted to close this question as a duplicate of one of our canonical [margin collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing) questions

Comment: @cimmanon: I reopened the question because it was marked as a duplicate of a question about spacing around images. You can vote to close the question if you have a proper duplicate.

Comment: Without myself knowing about collapsing margins I could not find an answer. I have searched using 'padding' and 'margin' and looked through the SO recommended questions before posting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your paragraph tag has a margin.

Apply this css rule:

```
.footer p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b09n7wzm/1/)

Comment: That worked great. Am I correct in saying that paragraphs come with a standard margin or padding?

Comment: here you have a question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can always CSS your way through it, something like

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

It should reset All elements, after that you define new paddings and margins, which is much easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your using a `<center>` tag if your using [HTML5 it's not supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)... if your not using HTML5 the `<center>` tag is a block element, add `display: inline-block` in the css.