# How to reset margin-bottom to its default value

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to set the `margin-bottom` of an element to its default value.

Consider the following example in which there are `h1` elements which have their respective `margin-bottom` style properties set to 0:

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>First Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>

<h1 id="normal-margin">Second Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

How can I reset the margin-bottom value of `#normal-margin` to its initial, default value? Obviously using `initial` won't work, [as the initial value of `margin-bottom` is 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom).

I realise in this trivial example I can simply add `:not(#normal-margin)` to the style definition of `h1` to fix the issue. I would however like a solution which would “undo” the margin and reset it to its initial value.

I’m thinking that I’m going to have to hard-code values into the CSS, which to me seems a bit cheap. Is that the only solution to this problem?

Comment: Not sure you can and, in any case, this is likely to be different for each browser. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css

Comment: @Paulie_D That's precisely why I asked this question in the first place, I'd like to maintain consistency between initial margin values in different browsers if at all possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are asking then...are not using a CSS reset or Normalize?

Comment: yes why not using Normalize and adding some classes where needed? You're just making your life more difficult in the long run styling html tags in your CSS (see OO CSS and methodologies like BEM to understand more about this)

Comment: I should have clarified – in my actual application of this problem, I have a style definition for some `h1` elements which, amongst other things, sets the `margin-bottom` of the respective element to 0. I’m looking for a way to undo that (i.e. set it to its initial value, as if I never set `margin-bottom` to 0). I'm also not using any CSS resets or the like, but I may consider it now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the property you're looking for is `unset`.

> `unset` resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or to its initial value if not. 
>   Via - [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/58/

```css
div {
  border: medium solid green;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
h2 {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

/* but make those in the sidebar use the value of the 'color' property (initial value) */
h2.specialHeader {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}
```

```html
<div><h2>Normal Header</h2></div>
<div><h2 class="specialHeader">Special Header</h2></div>
```

### Browser Support:

**Chrome:** > v.41

**FireFox:** > v.27

**Edge:** > v.13

**Opera:** > v.28

**Safari:** > v9.1

**IE:** Not Supported

[See caniuse for all (un-)supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=unset)

Comment: I saw this on the Mozilla developer page and attempted to use it, but with no luck as I was using Safari. However it seems to be the only solution to achieve what I'm after right now (without using CSS resets and the like).

Comment: Hmm, if you have one h2 tag with no rule and another with your special "unset class" these should look the same, right? .. wrong,or at least not in my test fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/65sf2f66/61/

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I removed your css and still it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/65sf2f66/62/

Comment: If only IE was supported.

Comment: @LGSon Yes, I tried just now and noticed the same thing. The margin on the header without unset uses some user agent properties (webkit in chrome) so that is based on the browser. Unset removes even those browser default properties which is even better as it's purpose is to completely remove element's properties.

Comment: Wasn't it suppose to set it to the the value as when the element never were set in the first place??

Comment: @LGSon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset ("or to its initial value if not.")

Comment: Since `margin-*` are not inherited, `unset` will behave exactly like `initial` which, as explained in the question, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Currently it's not possible. In some future, use the `revert` keyword**

As explained in [7.3. Explicit Defaulting](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#defaulting-keywords), there are 4 diferent defaulting behaviors:

- [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#initial) sets a property to its [initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#initial-value).

  In the case of `margin-*`, that's `0`.
- [`inherit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inherit) sets a property to the value of the parent element <sub><sup>(or to the initial value for the root element)</sup></sub>.
- [`unset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inherit-initial) behaves as `inherit` for inherited properties, and as `initial` otherwise.

  `margin-*` are not inherited, so it would produce `0`.
- The behavior of [`revert`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default) depends on the origin of the declaration

  - For user-agent origin, it behaves as `unset`
  - For user origin, it rolls back the cascade to the user-agent level, so that the specified value is calculated as if no author-level or user-level rules were specified for the property.
  - For author origin, it rolls back the cascade to the user level, so that the specified value is calculated as if no author-level rules were specified for the property.

So the behavior you want is `revert`'s one, i.e.

- The user-agent adds some margin to `h1` elements
- One of your (author) declarations removes that margin
- `revert` rolls back that to the margin defined by the user-agent

Note `revert` is a recent addition to the CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 4 spec, which is still only a draft. Therefore, browsers don't support it yet.