# How to minimize space between pargraphs on each line

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have about 5 paragraphs and they are describing things like "Name" "Member Since" and "Currency".

What do I do in CSS to shorten the height of them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNGAW.png
This is a shot. The green bits under the avatar are the fonts I want to appear closer to each other in terms of vertical alignment.

Any ideas?

THE HTML followed by the CSS

```css
.user-info-box {
 padding: 25px;
border: 25px;
margin: 25px;
border: 1px solid #2fac66;
}

p {
 color: #2fac66;  

}

#user-avatar {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #2fac66;
}

.avatar-detail {
    color: #2fac66;
}
```

```html
        <div class="user-info-box">
<img src="images/user-avatar.png" id="user-avatar">

<p class="avatar-detail">[Username]</p><p class="avatar-info">Captain Anderson</p>

<p class="avatar-detail">[Currency]</p>
<p class="avatar-info">1, 132</p></center>
        
        
<p class="avatar-detail">[Member Since]</p>
<p class="avatar-info">September 29th, 2014</p></center>
        
        
<p class="avatar-detail">[Profile]</p>
    <p class="avatar-info"> >> click here</p></center>

</div>
```

Comment: It's best if you can post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: There is often a default margin on `<p>` tags. See [What is the default...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css).

Comment: I edited the photo. sorry for not adding code. Added it

Comment: You can change line-height if you want the lines within the <p> tag tighter or change margin-bottom, if want the <p>s closer together.

Comment: Updated the post with an answer. Totally forgot about line height. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see your code but you can reset the margin and padding for the `<p>` tags like so,

```
p {margin: 0; padding:0;}
```

and then change the line height on the paragraph tags to the desired pixel height.

```
p {margin: 0; padding:0; line-height: 15px;}
```

Comment: line-height would be better expressed in %, so it's relative to font-size.

Answer (score 1):

```html
p {
Line height: 50%;
}
```

That did it. Thanks. Been working day job for 4 months. Only studied web for about half a year. Takes a little getting back into.

KUDOS!