# Vertically align fontawesome icon with text in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to vertically align a fontawesome icon with some text in a navbar from bootstrap. The vertical size of the navbar is set to `10vh`. I'm not able to get the text aligned with the icon, it appears like in the below image:

[image: Not aligned text]

Also I would like to add some horizontal space between the icon and the text. Here is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark h-100">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x icon-white"></i>
          <p>Home</p><!--<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>-->
        </a>
      </li>
      ... (some more li)
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I've also tried to put the icon inside the paragraph, placing the `a` element inside a `div`, and setting both of the same font-size, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: try using margin property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any other HTML and CSS noob like me, it seems that `p` elements have margin by default. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css) where it says that CSS 2.1 specification has a [default style sheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) for basic elements. Removing the bottom margin of the `p` element made it aligned with the icon.

Regarding horizontal space, [DIVYIA BAID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11318770/divya-baid)'s suggestion to set a left margin is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it worked for me:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark h-100">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" style="display: flex; align-items: center;" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x icon-white"></i>
          <p style="margin-left: 12px;">Home</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      ... (some more li)
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Also, here I'm giving the space between the text and the icon as 12px, you can change this according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the

tag a flex container with height 100% (obviously after setting  position: relative. Then you can easily do justify-content: center; and align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple

**Try This code for best alignment for Fontawesome or any other icon**

```
<li styles="display:flex">
   <a href="#" role="button" data-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
   <i class="fal fa-home" style="vertical-align: middle;margin: auto;"></i>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the content in a flex container and then align items center to horizontally align them.