# How to position div blocks without spacing

Tags: html, css

I encountered a strange behavior of nested `div-blocks`, which I wonder how it can be explained logically and how to avoid.

My minimalized `HTML` to demonstrate the behavior is as follows:

```css
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:gray;
}
#block1 {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:cyan;
    display: inline-block;
}
#block2{
  height:40%;
  background-color:green;
  /* the following lines actually have no effect
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  */
}
#block3{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demonstrate Strange CSS Behavior</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2">
        <div  id="block3">Hello!</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- This html will add a space between block1 and block2
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2">
        <div  id="block3"><span><p>Hello!</p></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
-->
<!-- This simple space will remove it again
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2">&nbsp;
        <div  id="block3"><span><p>Hello!</p></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Because there is no **padding** and **margin** the `div` blocks neatly overlap each other.
[Demonstration with JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phzf6gmy/)
When however a p-tag is wrapping the "Hello!" everything becomes strange. A space of about `10px` height appears between block1 and block2.
[See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dnt18ag2/)
This behavior does not show with an inline tag such as span, but it reappears with any block child node. And even more strange, when a non-breakable space is added after block2, the space between block1 and block2 is gone.
[See in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79tknL8e/)

How can a so distant child change the spacing between grand(grand...) parents?

**Update:** Having studied similar QA threads and the discussion about [CSS Reset](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/should-you-reset-your-css/), I arrived at the conclusion that CSS margin property is buggy and better avoided.To circumvent such problems use [CSS reset code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do) and positioning.

Comment: `p` has default margin-top/bottom. Set `p {margin: 0}`.

Comment: <p> tags do have a browser-native top- and bottom-margin

Comment: I ran and edited your snippet and didn't find any margins

Comment: @pavel Agree. It works as can be tested with JSFiddle, but that doesn't solve the problem as it only postpones it. As soon as an element node has a margin the gap between block1 and block2 will reappear. And it makes no sense to me that a margin of a grand child node will affect spacing of a grand parent node.

Comment: @Cedric Please see the JSFiddle examples I added.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're dealing with default browser styles. There have been several discussions around the issue of the default styling of the `p` tag, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css) for example)

> How can a so distant child change the spacing between grand(grand...) parents?

I can't answer that question, but I can suggest how to circumvent the issue: [CSS Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)