# how to reduce Space between Text and table ?HTML?

Tags: html

I think this is HTML. its for my companies online booking program (using squarespace)

I cannot figure out how to get rid of the big space between the text and the table.
There is a large vertical gap between"Wealth for Life. We deliver." and the table containing the addresses and images.

I have used the table to ensure the maps are spread evenly across the page.
I have tried setting cellspacing and cell padding to 0, but it didnt change anything.

most of my code is as below (hopefully pasting it here doesnt go weird)

```html
<p><span style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Wealth for Life. We deliver.
   </span>
</p>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th style="text-align:center;">25 Princes Way,<br>Drouin
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;">33 Kirk Street,<br>Moe
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;">18 Hotham Street,<br>Traralgon
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;">54A Ridgway,<br>Mirboo North
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="text-align:center;"><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"><img src="https://cdn-s.acuityscheduling.com/upload-44e575df9762f89001dfefa102459952.jpg" width="163" height="171" alt="upload-44e575df9762f89001dfefa102459952.jpg"></span></span>
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;"><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"><img src="https://cdn-s.acuityscheduling.com/upload-6b0d65075cb65df81cf457cdfb019d20.jpg" width="163" height="171" alt="upload-6b0d65075cb65df81cf457cdfb019d20.jpg"></span>
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;"><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"></span><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"><img src="https://cdn-s.acuityscheduling.com/upload-0d79df94975c07ec1ca2e0b8fd1e4a2e.jpg" width="163" height="171" alt="upload-0d79df94975c07ec1ca2e0b8fd1e4a2e.jpg"></span>
         </th>
         <th style="text-align:center;"><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"></span><span class="acuity-redactor-fix"><img src="https://cdn-s.acuityscheduling.com/upload-3dd2eb7719099b4c5d79ce929a29836d.jpg" width="163" height="171" alt="upload-3dd2eb7719099b4c5d79ce929a29836d.jpg"></span>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The gap is caused by the default margin of `<p>` tag, you can remove it by resetting its margin value (e.g. `<p style="margin: 0">`). See [What is the default padding and/or margin for a p element (reset css)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css)